# Deterministic name server addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

With AWS, how can I get deterministic name server addresses between terraform apply/destroy executions?

At the moment, my name servers are something like this:

```
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.com. 
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.org. 
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.net. 
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.co.uk.
```

And each time I run apply/destroy, the values of `XXX` and `YY` change.

So if I have a domain registered with godaddy/namecheap/other, then these also need to be updated, which takes time to propagate.

So I am wondering is there a way to influence what `XXX/YY` values are, so that they may persist between sessions?

For example, I tried this, and although it set the name servers as I had desired, unfortunately it wouldn't resolve.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "ns" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = "my_fixed_ns"
  ttl             = 30
  type            = "NS"
  zone_id         = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  records         = [
    "ns1.amazon.com",
    "ns2.amazon.org",
    "ns3.amazon.net",
    "ns4.amazon.co.uk"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would move this out to a separate terraform template that you aren't constantly destroying.

Comment: @markB Thanks, yeah thats basically what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reusable delegation sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-reusable-delegation-set) to make Route53 zones use the same name servers for each zone whether that's multiple concurrent zones or rebuilding the zone over and over:

> A set of four authoritative name servers that you can use with more than one hosted zone. By default, Route 53 assigns a random selection of name servers to each new hosted zone. To make it easier to migrate DNS service to Route 53 for a large number of domains, you can create a reusable delegation set and then associate the reusable delegation set with new hosted zones. (You can't change the name servers that are associated with an existing hosted zone.)

In Terraform these are created with the [`aws_route53_delegation_set` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_delegation_set.html) and the example given in the docs looks like this:

```
resource "aws_route53_delegation_set" "main" {
  reference_name = "DynDNS"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name              = "hashicorp.com"
  delegation_set_id = aws_route53_delegation_set.main.id
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "secondary" {
  name              = "terraform.io"
  delegation_set_id = aws_route53_delegation_set.main.id
}
```

If you're destroying the zones and rebuilding them and wanting the same name servers then you'll need to make sure not to destroy the delegation set at the same time.

You could do this by running `terraform destroy -target aws_route53_zone.example` if you wanted to select just the zone.

Alternatively you could create the delegation set in one directory and then the Route53 zones (plus anything else) in a separate directory and just not destroy the delegation set resource directory. So you'd have something like this:

```
.
├── delegation-set
│   └── delegation-set.tf
└── route53-zone
    └── route53-zone.tf


### delegation-set.tf

resource "aws_route53_delegation_set" "example" {
  reference_name = "Example"
}

output "delegation_set_id" {
  value = aws_route53_delegation_set.example.id
}

### route53-zone.tf

data "aws_route53_delegation_set" "example" {
  id = "INSERT_DELEGATION_SET_ID_HERE"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name              = "example.com"
  delegation_set_id = data.aws_route53_delegation_set.example.id
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see in the above example, the [`aws_route53_delegation_set` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_delegation_set.html) only takes the ID of a delegation set rather than be able to give it a caller reference so you'd need to hardcode the reference ID generated and outputted by running `terraform apply delegation-set`.

Alternatively you could use the [`terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) instead of the `aws_route53_delegation_set` data source:

```
### route53-zone.tf

data "terraform_remote_state" "delegation_set" {
  backend = "remote"

  config = {
    organization = "example"
    workspaces = {
      name = "delegation-set"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name              = "example.com"
  delegation_set_id = data.terraform_remote_state.delegation_set.id
}
```

The above configuration would need adapting for however you are storing your state.

Comment: have tried that, rebuilding zone yields different name-servers

Comment: Are you deleting the delegation set each time as well? That will reset the name servers. You'll need to keep the delegation set around and then just refer to it with the [delegation set data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/route53_delegation_set.html) in the location you are applying and destroying the Route53 zones.

Comment: Yeah, I ended splitting off the delegation set into a seperate state (call it state1), stored on S3 remote, and then in the project (call it state 2), referred to the output of state 1. that way I can deploy state1 and let it persist, and then apply/destroy state2 as is needed.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a longer, worked example of how to handle destroying and rebuilding the zones and keeping the name servers the same on each rebuild cycle.

Comment: Your alternate solution using the terraform remote state, is precisely what I did...

Comment: Ideally you'd be able to use the `aws_route53_delegation_set` data source to get at it by the caller ID but to do that needs a change the data source so that it loops through the list of data sources instead of just selecting by ID.

Comment: I have about 5 minutes of experience with Terraform, so I'm still banging rocks together, but I _believe_ the first dot in the line `value = aws_route53.delegation_set.example.id` near the middle of the second sample code should be an underscore. Please please please tell me this is just a typo and I'm actually beginning to understand a few things about Terraform ;-)